# Aurora serverless v2 instance doesn't scale down to minimum 0.5 ACU

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

We configured an Aurora Serverless V2 Postgresql in our cluster but unfortunately it doesn't scale down to 0.5 ACU. Our database size is around 700-800 gb.

Info about our setup: In our app there is a constant load and usage so we only route special requests to the serverless instance (from 7am to 5pm), during the off peak hours these requests are directed to the writer instance (which is not serverless)

Our instances:

1. In our cluster we have a write db which is not serverless it's a db.r6g.xlarge instance which is constantly under load.
2. We have another read instance which is a db.r6g.large instance it's responsible for a specific sync task, this is also always under constant load.
3. We have a 3rd instance which is the SERVERLESS V2 instance. We use it only for specific reading queries during peak time to serve the unpredictable and spiky load.

[A screenshot of our database instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfHAt.png)

So we have a mixed configuration and our issue is that when we don't send requests to the serverless instance it doesn't scale down to 0.5 but stays at around 2.5-3.5 ACUs.

What we did:

- We checked and we are sure the serverless v2 instance is not queried by us and all queries are redirected to the writer instance during the off peak hours.
- We turned off the Performance insight monitoring on the serverless instance.
  [Performance monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWUnZ.png)
- The log export is also turned off on the serverless instance.
  [Log export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZHjA.png)
- max_connections and max_locks_per_transaction is set to the default
- Failover priority is set to tier-2 on the serverless instance
  [Failover priority](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4KJg.png)

There is an image of the ACU usage from our Cloudwatch dashboard:
[ACU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RspH6.png)

There is a zoomed in version of the chart, you can see regular spikes and random high ACU usage (+ the baseline should be 0.5ACU too): [Zoomed in ACU usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2CFa.png)

I marked the off peak hours with red in the screenshot and as you can see there are random spikes and constant usage. Not that as high when we send queries but there is something definitely going on there.

Can you please help us with this issue?

Comment: Off peak hours, is the app still "connected" to the serverless instance? Maybe it's not running queries, but the connection pool still keeps a few/many connections active all the time.

Comment: Can I monitor this somehow in cloudwatch? The app is connected but no request should be sent there.

Comment: @TheImpaler I added a zoomed in version of the chart in my original post you can see there are regular spikes.

Comment: From that zoomed-in chart, you appear to have something that is issuing some fairly heavy query against your database every minute. The only real way to debug this is to enable slow query logs, with `0` seconds min duration so that all queries get logged, and then look at the log after a few minutes to see what those queries are, and go from there.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you.

Is this how I set it?

1. I create a separate parameter group for the serverless instance
2. I set "log_min_duration_statement" to 0
3. I guess (?) I need to turn this on in the instance settings: "Log exports Select the log types to publish to Amazon CloudWatch Logs PostgreSQL log"
4. Watch the result in Cloudwatch?

Also, do I need to turn on performance insight? I was told that also boosts ACU usage.

Comment: @MarkB Also, do you think these regular heavy queries don't let my instance to go down below 2.5-3 ACU and get down to the 0.5?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I think, which is why I said you need to do some debugging/investigation into what those queries are.

Comment: You don't need to turn on performance insights unless you want to use performance insights to debug those queries. You don't need to turn on CloudWatch logs exports unless you want to look at the query log in CloudWatch logs. After enabling slow query logs, you can simply go to the logs section in the RDS/Aurora instance dashboard to view the logs. CloudWatch logs is a much better interface with more features, but it isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

- disable performance insights
- look under maintenance and backups for an pending upgrades.  You may need to apply these upgrades to get your database to scale down
- upgrade your engine version, if possible (I'm not sure if this actually helps but it's one of the steps I took to get down to 0.5)